# MIUI: Turn off auto flash off feature with power button

Tags: miui-12, flashlight

My Device: POCO M2 Pro

Useless Feature: If flashlight is on and screen is turned off, then pressing the power button will turn off the flashlight first instead of waking the screen.

My Question: How to disable this feature? It is set like this by default and there are no settings to change it.

If my screen is off, I can't turn it on when my phone's flashlight is being used for some purpose where a temporary cut off from light source would be a problem.

Disabling MIUI optimisations and then doing something is not preferred. Double tap to wake screen gestures etc. are not solutions to my problem. What if I press the power button accidentally!

Thank you in advance. **Any suggestions are welcome.**